# Change image when collision is detected in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to change the image of the enemy `SKSpriteNode` when the player collides, but in the game I will have many enemies and I want to change only the selected one.

`Enemy.name` is the number of lives, I don't know if I can do this differently.

```
func setupPlayer(){
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
    player.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 60)
    player.zPosition = Layer.Player.rawValue
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width / 2)
    player.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.7
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory 
    worlNode.addChild(player)
    nuevoPlayerControl = true
}

func setupEnemy(){
    if nuevoPlayerControl == true && nuevoPlayer == true{
        enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        enemy.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        enemy.zPosition = Layer.Player.rawValue
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 300)
        enemy.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        enemy.zRotation = player.zRotation
        enemy.size = player.size
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemy.size.width/2)
        enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 1
        enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory 
        enemy.name = "3"
        worlNode.addChild(enemy)
    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    }
    else  {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }
    if body1.categoryBitMask == playerCategory && body2.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory {
        //here the enemy lose a live and the image should change
        let lives = body2.node?.name
        if lives! == "3" {
            body2.node?.name = "2"
        }
        if lives! == "2" {
            body2.node?.name = "1"
        }
        if lives! == "1" {
            body2.node?.removeFromParent()
        }
        print(lives)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just take the body's node in your didBeginContact and change the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need you can always write a custom class for enemy that inherits from SKSpriteNode where you can have a property called `numLives` so you can use the name string for this purpose and get the number of lives through `enemy.numLives`. The easiest thing might be to use the first part of the `name` string  for number of lives and the second part for your enemy identification, and when you need either the number of lives or name, you just parse it to get what you want. For example:

```
//when you create an enemy:
enemy.name = "3 bigEnemy"
```

Then if you need to access it either parse/loop through with for-in or take the part of the string you need with `subStringWithRange`:

```
//to get the number of lives:
let lives = enemy.name.substringWithRange(NSRangeMake(0, 1))
//to get the name of the enemy:
let name = enemy.name.substringWithRange(NSRangeMake(3, enemy.name.length))
```

You are on the right track for changing the image when colliding. All you have left to do is change the `body.node`'s texture. If you have an image you just use:

```
var textureToChangeTo: SKTexture = SKTexture.textureWithImage("yourImageNameHere")
body.node?.texture = textureToChangeTo
```